# C language - (compile and run but command (cmd.exe) does not appear

Tags: c, cmd

I am practising C but I am having problem with this.

I am using wxDev C++ and I ran the file (it says compiles and runs fine) but the problem is that the result does not appear at all (command prompt (cmd.exe) is not appearing).

I am currently using Windows 7 using MacBookPro (as bootcamp).

What can be the potential solutions toward this problem?

Thank you very much

e.g. even this simple code

```
int main(void){
    printf("Hello, world");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: If your program terminates to quickly you won't see a command prompt. Is it possible that this is the problem? Try running it from a command prompt instead of just double clicking it.

Comment: Put a getchar() before the last bracket in your code or execute it via a terminal.

Comment: even if I do that it ...still runs like this.

Comment: I see no reason why cmd.exe would appear. Just just runs your program. Run it's through cmd.exe manually.

Comment: If the cmd executes so fast that you don't see its output, you could use :`./cmd >myoutput`, and look at the resulting file. I would also advise to add "!\n" at the end of the string, and `#include <stdio.h>` at the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 0):

The getch() function is waiting for you to press a key before it returns control to the program. The program will not finish executing until you type 1 character.

See http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/conio.h/getch , which shows a similar program to yours.